# Regular Expression Words stuck together

Tags: regex, qtp

Is there a way to write regular expressions to stop right before a particular word or characters?

For example, I have a text like:

> Advisor:HarrisTeamTeamRole

So I want to write a regular expression that makes the advisor name dynamic, but only capture Harris. How do I write a regular expression to stop right before Team?

Comment: QTP uses VBScript as the language

Comment: Yes, VBScript in QTP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a lookbehind and lookahead like this:

```
(?<=Advisor:).*?(?=Team)
```

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/kL5bOf1x1rPBo0Wf)

This will only capture from "Advisor:" up to the first "Team", and the regex will not capture anything else after (including "Team") in a capture group or otherwise. This will require a type of regex that can do lookbehinds... if you are not using that, you'll have to use grouping... which could be as simple as:

```
Advisor:(.*?)Team
```

and then just get the capture group #1

Comment: Awesome, this worked. I only had to look ahead, so it stops at Team. So I just used Advisor:.*?(?=Team) and it worked!

Comment: @user3911803 Sure if you want to also capture "Advisor:" that would work as well, but I thought you only wanted "Harris" in which case you would have to use both the lookarounds... or pull from a capture group.

Comment: Oops, I guess I didn't make it clear in my Original Post. But yea I'll keep this method in mind; really useful.

Thank you!

Comment: `Advisor` is Dynamic as per OP

Comment: @user3218114, OP says the advisor's name is dynamic - the word "Advisor" is not dynamic.

Comment: Got it, I was confused.

Answer (score 2):

You can try in **Lazy** way and get the matched group from index 1

```
^Advisor:(.*?)Team
```

Here is [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/iT4eX9/10)

Answer (score 2):

[Try this one](http://rubular.com/r/XtcawMrdtH)

This regular expression would be:

`:([A-Z][a-z]*)`

This one captures only the first word after the colon as long as it's in CamelCase, meaning it doesn't have to be the word `Team` it could be `Advisor:HarrisNetworkSomething` as well.

Comment: This may work in most cases, but there may be some unforeseen problems... for instance if an advisor's name is "McDonald"... or if the OP doesn't want to include matches that aren't preceded by "Advisor" and/or proceeded by "Team".

Comment: I agree smerny. In this case this method also works, but I could see scenarios where it won't.